# Is there a way to find which IP I am connected to?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

Let's say my `eth0` interface has multiple IP addresses and I can connect with SSH to any of these.  Is there a way to find out which of those I am connected to?

(The background is that certain operations, like removing an IP from the host, is better not done from the given IP address.  To avoid this, I want to check this first, before I am closing myself out.)

Comment: I'm a little confused. When you connect via ssh, you do something like "ssh user@IP_ADDRESS" right? Or are you looking for the source of the connection?

Comment: @barrycarter The example mentioned in the question makes it quite clear why he is interested in the server IP rather than the client IP. If you connect using a hostname, which resolves to multiple IPs, you won't automatically know, which one you are connected to.

Comment: @kasperd OK, but then why not connect to "ssh user@IP_ADDRESS" instead? Seems much easier?

Comment: @barrycarter If you find the need to know in the middle of a session, it is easier to type `echo "$SSH_CONNECTION"` than to log out and start a new ssh connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply type:

```
echo "$SSH_CONNECTION"
```

Or if you want only the server IP address and not the other fields:

```
echo "$SSH_CONNECTION" | cut -f3 -d' '
```

If you are using `screen` and reconnect to a previously started `screen` session, notice that running these commands inside `screen` will show the connection from which `screen` was started and not the session where you reconnected to `screen`.

Comment: Or `echo "$SSH_CONNECTION" | awk '{print $1}'` if you prefer `awk` over `cut`.

Comment: @ThoriumBR That would have to be `$3`.

Comment: Thanks, especially for mentioning `screen` - sometimes we do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use netstat and check for connections in there.

```
user@host:~$ sudo netstat -ntp
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
tcp      128      0 123.45.67.89:50212         98.76.54.32:22            ESTABLISHED 16774/ssh
[more stuff removed]
```

Comment: In my case, this boils down to `netstat -ntp | grep :22`.